# Get available RAM in Java

Tags: java, linux, memory

I'm trying to get the amount of available RAM of a system in a Java application, specifically on Linux but it needs to be cross platform.  Not the amount of memory available to the JVM, the actual physical RAM that is available.  Not the free RAM either, I mean available.

I tried using the OperatingSystemMXBean but it only returns free RAM: of course the problem is that Linux will consume free RAM as disk cache in order to speed up the system, reducing the "free" amount to almost zero even though the kernel will dump that cache at any time if more RAM is needed, hence the need for an "available" value.

So after a week or so my app will start complaining that my system is almost out of RAM, and I look at it like "no, the system may only have 100MB RAM free, but it's got 3GB of disk cache it can free up as needed".

Even "used" memory would be more useful than free.  Every tutorial I read on getting "used" RAM says to use "total - free": not the same thing.  Total - Used != available either, but it's closer than "free" and would give me more accurate tracking.

I feel like I've got to be missing something.  "Free" RAM isn't a very useful metric in most cases; whenever someone says they want "free" RAM they almost always mean "available", how much more RAM can be used by applications.  I'm pretty sure they're the same thing on Windows, but in *nix the distinction between "free" and "available" is incredibly important and it seems like a major oversight on Oracle/Sun's part.

Comment: The OS promises you a certain quota (maybe ...) of **virtual** memory, and you can generally find out how much of that your language-environment has currently allocated.  System-wide "available memory" is not a useful metric because it's strictly under the control of the OS, which will always use it for *some* purpose which may or may not be "process memory."  As various demands for that resource ebb and flow over time, the OS reacts accordingly.  But it maintains its promise to your application:  that, up to your quota (if any), you will be given the [virtual] memory you ask for.

Comment: https://crunchify.com/java-runtime-get-free-used-and-total-memory-in-java/

Comment: I'm not trying to get the amount of memory for the JVM, I want the amount of system memory.

Comment: Why do you need to know it? Your program shouldn't care about the memory. Either there's enough memory for the program, or there isn't. All the time you spend on this will be time wasted, as no proper Java programs attempt to manage memory while they're trying to accomplish their actual purpose.

Comment: There is no way to do that I think, but as @Kayaman says, whats the purpose if this requeriment?

Comment: It's a network management server: it monitors other hardware on the network and needs to be able to monitor and report on itself as well.  If the system runs out of memory and starts swapping, or the kernel decides to kill the NMS, or any other myriad of things as a result, that would be very bad, so someone suggested building in an early warning system, when physical RAM is "low", generate an internal alert.  Works fine on Windows, but starts complaining on Linux because of the aforementioned free vs available in *nix.

Comment: @WizardStan do not build one yourself. Get an existing product that works, and you'll save time and you won't have to solve these kinds of problems. Their feature set is also a lot larger than what you will be able to build yourself.

Comment: @kayaman I literally shouldn't be needing to justify myself giving all these fiddly details but since people on this god forsaken site seem to need the entire backstory before they'll give you a straight answer then YES that is literally what we have. We have a product.  The company we purchased it from is using com.sun.OperatingSystemMXBean.getFreePhysicalMemorySize() which, as I said, is effectively useless and getting them to change it is a "customization" that they want large amounts of money for but if I can easily change it to anything else that'd be so much nicer.

Comment: @kayaman The fact that you're telling me to "get an existing product" tells me that you are aware of a product that does monitor the memory as I expect which means that it must be possible.  HOW?!? How is it possible?

Comment: @WizardStan if nothing else, through native code. And I want the backstory because I don't trust the people who ask questions. It's not that they're deceitful on purpose, but relevant information is left out when people go in the "just answer my question!" mode. Maybe you need to evaluate some other monitoring solutions. Maybe you need to rethink your approach, so this won't be an issue no longer. It's not just magic code snippets that are used to solve problems, like you're hoping here.

Comment: I was specific about what I was asking. I said what I needed to do, I said what I had done, I gave a full paragraph on why it had failed and why this failure was important. I understand your concern, I've been in the industry for almost 40 years and have helped people since usenet days and know that what many ask for is not what they actually want, hence the need to dig deeper, but "just buy a solution" is a failure of an answer. This is a programming website: doesn't matter why they want it, if they ask a programming question you should give a programming answer.

Comment: Like, I don't even need JNI for this, this can, 100%, be done in Java: if System.getProperty("os.name") is Linux, read /proc/meminfo for the "MemAvailable" line and parse the number, otherwise use OperatingSystemMXBean to get free memory, put it in a wrapper and call it a day. It's a trivial problem with a trivial solution that anyone could've just given but no, too caught up in why anyone could possibly want such a thing, despite the fact that the language itself gives it, just poorly, which is the other part of my question: why?

Comment: @WizardStan Why? Because Java is very specific to the JVM. Any time you need to wonder about which platform you're on or what the native resources are, you're outside of the core purpose of Java. Like I said **if nothing else**, through native code, I didn't claim it was the only way. I've been writing Java for over 20 years and it's not a universal tool for everything. Your requirement is not a common case for Java software, since Java mainly cares about its own platform, the JVM.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's a common case or not, it was a problem that I had and your answer was "buy something".  That's an extremely unhelpful solution.  I wanted to know, since we already had "free" memory if there was a way to get "available" memory and explained why this was important.  I'll repeat that again, slower and more precisely: there is a formal and supported way of getting total and free memory of the system in Java, but free memory is not actually useful; it is not by any stretch unusual to ask if the actual useful information, available memory, can also be obtained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet solves the problem.

```
public static long getAvailableMem()
{
    String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
    if (osName.equals("Linux"))
    {
        try {
            BufferedReader memInfo = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/meminfo"));
            String line;
            while ((line = memInfo.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.startsWith("MemAvailable: "))
                {
                    // Output is in KB which is close enough.
                    return java.lang.Long.parseLong(line.split("[^0-9]+")[1]) * 1024;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    // We can also add checks for freebsd and sunos which have different ways of getting available memory
    } else
    {
        OperatingSystemMXBean osBean = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
        com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean sunOsBean = (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean)osBean;
        return sunOsBean.getFreePhysicalMemorySize();
    }
    return -1;
}
```